# programmatically trigger to .change event with jquery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

Is there a way to programmatically trigger to .change event with *jQuery*/*javascript*?

I want a piece of code that will fire a DOM `change` event for a select/option box such as the following:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' class='none'>
    <select name='ACTC' class='none cl_preAction' >
    <option data-location='S' value='001'>Fire</option>
    <option data-location='T' value='002'>Flood</option>
    <option data-location='T' value='003'>End Of World</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just call [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$(".cl_preAction").change();
```

> Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger
>   that event on an element.

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger an event using the trigger function of jQuery.

$(".none select").trigger('change');

> "Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event."

Comment: Think that wasn't the question ... trigger() to simulate and change() to capture the event.

Comment: Not quite the answer to the question, but of value to me on a related question, and google directed me here

Comment: calling `change()` without passing in a function runs `trigger('change')`;.